# JQuery - replace image on hover

Tags: jquery

I have an images folder. Within this folder, I have several images of two types; one `png` and one `gif`.  The displayed image is the `png` version. On an image hover, I need to replace it with its `gif` version.  And when hover is out, put the `png` version back in place.

I currently have the following which works

```
$(".image-container").mouseover(function () {
    var imgName = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var img2 = imgName.substring(0, imgName.lastIndexOf("."));
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", img2+".gif");
}).mouseout(function () {
    var imgName = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var img2 = imgName.substring(0, imgName.lastIndexOf("."));
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", img2+".png");
});
```

It works, but I dont like the way I am repeating things.  Is there any way to make this more efficient?

Thanks

Comment: Have a peek at [CodeReview.SE] (but be careful to check their FAQ for what's on topic though).

Comment: Use css classes instead to change background url - and add/remove class on hover, much cleaner and easier to manage imo

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would say, use `data-*` attributes in a better way. I would suggest you to have something like this:

```
<img src="img.png" data-src="img.png" data-hover="img.gif" alt="" class="image-container" />
```

And in the jQuery:

```
$(".image-container").mouseover(function () {
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("hover"));
}).mouseout(function () {
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("src"));
});
```

Or in short, you can also use `.replace()`. You **don't need** `regex` for this simple replacement:

```
$(".image-container").mouseover(function (e) {    
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", ".gif"));
}).mouseout(function (e) {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(".gif", ".png"));
});
```

Comment: +1 The first part of this answer is better architecture in general. The less magic assumptions in your code, the better.

Comment: @Matt Thanks buddy. `:)` And you were lightning fast and votes were too, before I answered. I got a stupid phone call. LoL.

Comment: @Matt Oh! How stupid of me to miss that! Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 8):

If you expand your selector to include `img` you can just use `$(this)` to reference it. And if you're just replacing `gif` with `png` (and vice-versa), it is easy to do that with regex.

```
$(".image-container img").mouseover(function (e) {    
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.png$/, '.gif'));
}).mouseout(function (e) {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.gif$/, '.png'));
});
```

**Edit**: Please also see [Praveen Kumar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34768005/) as well for a great suggestion of declaring filenames in `data-` attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the referral Matt! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `css` `:hover`

```css
.image-container {
  display:block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature)
              , url(http://lorempixel.com/50/50/cats);
  background-size: 100% 100%, 0% 0%;
}

.image-container:hover {
  background-size: 0% 0%, 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution,

You can also use event handler delegation and pass parameters to it.

***E.g.***

```
function replaceImageHandler(ev)
{
    var $img = $(this).find('img');
    var imgSrc = $img.attr('src');
    var toImg = imgSrc.substring(0, imgSrc.lastIndexOf(".")) + '.' + ev.data.ext;
    $img.attr('src', toImg)
}

$(".image-container")
    .on('mouseover', { ext: 'gif'}, replaceImageHandler)
    .on('mouseout', { ext: 'png'}, replaceImageHandler);
```

You can also operate this if you want to attach more event handlers.

***E.g.***

```
function replaceImageHandler(ev)
{
    var $img = $(this).find('img');
    $img.attr('src', ev.data.src);
}

$(".image-container")
    .on('click', { src: 'zoom-my-image.gif'}, replaceImageHandler)
    .on('mouseover', { src: 'my-image-1.gif'}, replaceImageHandler)
    .on('mouseout', { src: 'my-image-2.png'}, replaceImageHandler);
```

Answer (score -2):

better way to implement this through css

```
.image-container:hover{
    url: imagepath;

  }
```

Comment: What about dynamic images, say 100 images. And `url:`? Does it even work?

Comment: Man, are you sure you need the wrong answer in here?