# .hover() Jquery In need of assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue implementing a jquery feature that will allow me to hover over an image and change the image, then when not hovering have it revert to original image. This is what I have so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="slideshow">
        <img src="myPic.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="pic" id="myImage"/>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#myImage").hover(function(){
    $("#myImage").attr("src", "http://timesofoman.com/uploads/images/2017/05/21/671029.JPG");
    },function() {
        $("#myImage").attr("src", "myPic.jpg");
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Just use a css :hover rule, no need for Javascript at all here.

Comment: What issue are you experiencing here? The code provided works if you remove the last curly brace. You can easily verify this if you insert your code into a Stack Overflow Code Snippet and use a placeholder image for the initial image (e.g: replace `myPic.jpg` with `https://placehold.it/400x300` ), then give it a spin (don't forget to include jQuery).

Comment: I was almost certain code was fine. What do you guys mean when you say possible duplicate?

Comment: Nothing was working. What do you mean by a duplicate. Unsure why this will not work

Comment: Just remove the last curly brace (`}`).

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `mouseout` event if you want to change image on mouse out.

```
$("#myImage").hover(function(){
  $(this).attr("src", 
     "http://timesofoman.com/uploads/images/2017/05/21/671029.JPG");
  }).on("mouseout",function(){
  $(this).attr("src", "myPic.jpg");
});
```

```js
$("#myImage").hover(function(){
      $(this).attr("src", 
         "http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/other-states/article20605531.ece/alternates/LANDSCAPE_460/20TH-THGRP-RUPANI");
      }).on("mouseout",function(){
      $(this).attr("src", "http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/article20601353.ece/alternates/FREE_460/21THCRPF-02");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="myImage" src="http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/other-states/article20605531.ece/alternates/LANDSCAPE_460/20TH-THGRP-RUPANI" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$("#myImage").hover(function(){
  $("#myImage").attr("src", "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/185bd9/ffffff&text=hover+image");
},function() {
  $("#myImage").attr("src", "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" width="400" height="300" alt="pic" id="myImage"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#image").hover(function(){
        $("#image").attr("src","https://img.teleflora.com/images/o_0/l_flowers:t17t100a,pg_6/w_272,h_340,cs_no_cmyk,c_pad,g_south/f_auto,q_auto:eco,e_sharpen:200/flowers/t17t100a/Teleflora'sCountryOvenCenterpiece");
      },function(){
        $("#image").attr("src","https://fyf.tac-cdn.net/images/products/large/TEV12-4.jpg");
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" src="https://fyf.tac-cdn.net/images/products/large/TEV12-4.jpg">
```

The only thing I can think of is one of your links doesn't work or is not set up right. That or an extra "}" you may have placed as in your original post there is one after the code block.

Comment: Before answering a question check for duplicate posts. Someone might have provided a solution for this. Also, try to add snippets if you want to show user that code is working.

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to use hard coded image `src` and `alt-src`. Like in eCommerce website you will have different product images, so that jQuery part should be independent of the html. Here is the approach I would like to recommend (using custom attribute `data-*`)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image test</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <image src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/300" class="product" data-alt-src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/300/E494FF"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".product").hover(function() {
                    if(!$(this).attr("data-src")) {
                        $(this).attr("data-src", $(this).attr("src"));
                        //console.log($(this).attr("data-src"));
                    }
                    if($(this).attr("data-alt-src")) {
                        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-alt-src"));
                    }
                }, function() {
                    if($(this).attr("data-src")) {
                        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please look on the SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767900/jquery-replace-image-on-hover also. But the requirement and approach chosen has some differences,

Answer (score 0):

**very simple example easy onhover change images in jquery:--**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sourceSwap = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
        $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
        $this.attr('src', newSource);
    }

    $(function() {
        $('img[data-alt-src]').each(function() { 
            new Image().src = $(this).data('alt-src'); 
        }).hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap); 
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<img data-alt-src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/accept.png" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/cancel.png" />
<br/>
<img data-alt-src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/accept.png" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/cancel.png" />




</body>
</html>
```